# Como executar o INSERT apenas se o registo não existir?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Gostaria de usar algo do género em [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite)

```
insert into table (column) values ('')if not exist;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar `INSERT OR IGNORE`.

Para isso a(s) coluna(s) em causa deve(m) ser declarada(s) como `UNIQUE`.

Quando há a violação de uma restrição(constraint) ela é tratada de acordo com o indicado na *conflict clause* da [constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html) declarada para a coluna, que por padrão é *abort*.
Caso seja declarada ou não ela pode ser sobrescrita no comando INSERT:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (column) VALUES ('')
```

Assim a violação da restrição é ignorada.

Veja [INSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) e [ON CONFLICT clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar uma *unique* para evitar a repetição se for o caso.
Encontrei o exemplo abaixo em https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php

```
CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  hire_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (last_name, first_name)
);
```

Além disso você também pode utilizar um *select* junto com o *insert* para realizar a validação.
Utilizando a tabela anterior, poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
 insert into employees(last_name, first_name, hire_date)

 select 
    'Stuart','John','1990-01-01' 
 from 
    employees 
 where 
    not exists(select 1 from employees where first_name = 'john')
```

Quando a consulta não tiver resultados, não realizará o insert e você pode realizar qualquer filtragem no *where*.

Comment: sim eu fiz isso mas queria fazer isso no proprio insert

Comment: Adicionei outra forma de realizar o insert na minha resposta anterior